# Обращение к элементу двухмерного списка: index error

Tags: python, list, if, index, range

Хочу обратиться к элементу двумерного списка, а тут IndexError: list index out of range, хотя в другом коде аналогичная конструкция работает

```
a,b=map(int,input().split())
d=[]
e=0
f=0
g=0
h=0
j=0
def split(c):
    return[char for char in c]
for i in range(a):
    c=str(input())
    d.append(split(c))
for x in range(a):
    for y in range(b):
        if d[x][y]=='S':
            e=e+1
    if e==0:
        f=f+1
        d.remove(d[x])
    e=0
b=b-f
h=h+f*a
for y in range(b):
    for x in range(a):
        if d[y][x]=='S':
            j=j+1
    if j==0:
        g=g+1
        d.remove(d[y])
    j=0
h=h+g*a
print(h)
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
if d[x][y]=='S':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Не понимаю, почему, ведь d - это двумерный список, по двум индексам x и y должна быть возможность обращаться к элементу списка. Ведь следующий код с вводом с клавиатуры аналогичного списка работает:

```
a,b=map(int,input().split())
d=[]
def split(c):
    return[char for char in c]
for i in range(a):
    c=str(input())
    d.append(split(c))
print(d)
```

Ввожу это:

```
3 4
S...
....
..S.
```

И вывод верный:

```
[['S', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', 'S', '.']]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такая ошибка выходит в первом коде (в начале вопроса)? Ввод двумерного списка с клавиатуры вроде как корректный, о чём говорит работа второго кода, но в полном коде, который должен исполнять нужную мне функцию, ошибка.

Comment: а что вы в d удаляете? вот туда и попадаете, например

Comment: вы из d удаляете строку если в ней нет символа S. Таким образом удаляется вторая строка ввода. И к моменту когда x принимает значение 2 в матрице d всего две строки (то есть с индексом 2 уже ничего нет) . Выход за пределы, о чем вам и сообщается. Добавьте вывод на экран d,x,y перед вашим if что-бы наглядно это увидеть.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитал лишь заголовок... и так прежде чем, обратится к элементу списка, нужно вывести его размер, то же относительно субсписко-субэлементов

```
l=[[1,2],[3,4]]
print(len(l))
#2
#значит что можно обратится лишь к элементу на еденицу меньше, так как отсчёт с нуля, грубо говоря реальный нулевой индекс, наш счёт один
l[0]
#[1,2]
#то же самое относится и к подспискам, прежде чем обращаться к индексу нужно узнать его длину
l[0][0]
#1
```

часто встречаются ошибки со счётчиком, у которого не верно заданы границы

```
l=[1,2]
for it in range(1,2): #in range(1,len(l))
   print(l[it]) #ошибка тк Л не имеет элемента с индексом два, но его длина два элементу
```

**Вывод всех задействованых переменных перед строкой с ошибкой помогает понять причину ошибки, модуль IC несколько помагает в этом**